# To modify or not to modify the EDMX file

Tags: entity-framework

Is it generally a good idea to manually modify the generated EDMX file when working on a .NET project? I had a project once where the developers were modifying the edmx file manually, and it was accepted as a rule to never regenerate the whole EDMX file. For example, one change we made was with some fields whereby we changed them to enum values.

Then I was hired on a project where the developers were telling me to regenerate the EDMX file whenever I made database changes. This was a totally different point of view.

So what is the better solution? Has anyone had any nightmares where one was better than the other.

Comment: `"it was accepted as a rule to never regenerate the EDMX"` - That reaks of something that started as a one-time workaround and quickly became a gospel rule.  Regardless of the subject matter, any time that happens it's a *clear* indication of an unhealthy codebase and a dysfunctional team.

Comment: It was a general rule to never regenerate the whole EDMX file. Partial classes were used but we were never allowed to delete all the tables in the designer and add back all the tables, like I was asked to do in my second project. The developers in the first project were modifying properties of fields to associate them to enums and that is why we were not allowed to regenerate those specific tables.

Comment: Honestly, "general rules" like that are just asking for trouble.  It makes for unintuitive use of industry tools and adds more manual steps to what should be a less manual process.  This leads to human error, high on-boarding costs, and lower productivity.  The costs are the big one.  As "general rules" like this add up over time, it takes longer for a new team member to become productive and a greater training investment is lost when a team member leaves.

Answer (score 2):

A general rule is not to edit any auto generated file whether it's EDMX or WinForms designer. However, if there is absolutely no other way and you do need to edit auto-generated class, then do it by using `partial` class. This way your change won't get lost after the class is regenerated.